# Why user didn't logout after browser closed in Yii?

Tags: authentication, yii, logout

This problem isset only in Chrome and Firefox. Opera and Safari works fine.
On login, I don't checking rememberMe option.

**allowAutoLogin** set to TRUE

Here is my login method from LoginForm model:

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->_identity === NULL)
    {
        $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($this->login, $this->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if ($this->_identity->errorCode === UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration = $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity, $duration);
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

And here is my action:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model = new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if (isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if ($model->validate() && $model->login()) $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login', array('model' => $model));
}
```

Comment: What, exactly, is the question?

Comment: Why user didn't logout after browser closing?

Comment: Please edit the question so that others can understand what you're asking. The title says "Yii app", but you don't even state what .js library you're invoking.

Comment: Js? Default Yii package.

Comment: Post your code. We are not supposed to guess what code you have written. Post your `loginForm` model and `action`

Answer (score 1):

In the config (*protected/config/main.php*) you can change **allowAutoLogin** to **false**

```
'components' => array(
    'user' => array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin' => false,
    ),
```

Read more about Yii login states here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser

Comment: Nothing happens, same problem.

Comment: Logout and clear the browser cache, and login again. the cookie may still be set from before.